# Как сделать теги выбранных свойств в фильтре на 1С-Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите пож-та, CMS 1С-Битрикс, есть фильтр на стандартном компоненте catalog.smart.filter, хочу чтоб при выборе свойств формировались отдельно теги выбранных свойств, например в контентной части над товарами, как на скриншоте. Направьте в нужном направлении, как такое сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]